# Как лучше всего вести историй операции в кошельке? Питон и Sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite3

Я смог написать больше половины команд для создания простого кошелья (пополнение, снятие наличных, перевод с одногот на другой счёт кошелька). Но я уже слоиал голову как мне вести историю операции?
Код написан на python, данные о пользователе хранться в базе данных sqllite 3.
Каждый раз, когда пользователь поплняет, снимает деньги или переводит другому человеку нужно sql добавлять новое событие:
Например, 17/10/21 21:24. Петров Иван пополнил свой счёт на сумму 234р.

Comment: вон та штука не подойдёт ? https://habr.com/ru/post/533040/

Comment: Не хочется переписывать код, учитывая то, что через три дня сдавать проект
А так спасибо за совет

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.